# Python 3, *args, print the output in a list

Tags: python, args

```
def even_number(*args):
    for even in args:
        if even%2==0:
            even
            print(list(str(even)),end='')
```

I want to print the output in a list as `[8,6,4]`, but rather it prints it out as `[8],[6],[4]`. If I put out the last print statement and just `print(even)`, it obviously doesn't list out the output.

Comment: Rather than telling people to ignore the indentation, would you mind fixing it?

Comment: The indention got odd while typing it out here. It’s the usual in the IDE.

Comment: Also, do you think that a title like "Python 3, *args" is very specific to your problem and descriptive? I have seen that you tend to use short titles which give no clue regarding the actual problem. This is not good, IMHO.

Comment: I added the rest which makes it more descriptive now, I think. Thank you for the suggestions though.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you print every time you enter in your if.
Instead, you want to add your number to a list every time you enter the loop and then print it :

```
def even_number(*args):
     my_list = list()
     for even in args:
        if even%2==0:
            my_list.append(even)
     print(my_list)
```

EDIT : 
The others answer are correct by the way. It's better to use the comprehension list. I don't remove my answer so you get to understand what your mistake was.

Comment: This prints out some more outputs as well. The last being the one which I want.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your comment. Could you please clarify "the last being the one which I want"?

Answer (score 0):

```
def even_number(*args):
  print([i for i in args if i % 2 == 0])
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to collect the result before printing it if you want to print it as a list, i.e.:

```
def even_number(*args):
    evens = [a for a in args if a % 2 == 0]
    print(evens)
# test:
even_number(*range(10))  # [0, 2, 4, 6, 8]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use a list comprehension with:

```
def even_number(*args):
    even = [n for n in args if n % 2 == 0]
    print(even)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple code

```
def even_number(*args):
    result = []
    for even in args:
        if even % 2 == 0:
            result.append(even)
    return result
```

with comprehension list

```
def even_number(*args):
    result = [x for x in args if x%2==0]
    return result
```

for to use function even_number

```
print even_number(range(10))
```